# How to Align Elements to Left and Right Without position absolute or float

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

As per the title, I am looking for a way to align content to either side of their parent element without the usage of position absolute or floating. The reason for this is that I need to parent element to retain it's height: using either of these methods removes the children elements from the flow, thus it's parent has no height.

Is there any way to do this?

#### The Structure

div.parentElement

----div.left

--------div.image

----div.right

--------article

------------h1

------------p

I have tried using margin-left: 0; margin-right; 0; text-alight: right or left. I have even tried wrapping divs .left & .right in another div and giving them the same properties: no method I have tried has worked.

Comment: text-align:left .. text-align;right; .. flex .. margin-left:auto .. margin-right:auto ... etc,etc. Show us what did you try and where you failed

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have indeed tried margin left and right auto, along with the text aligns. They haven't worked.

Comment: you need to show us then so we can correct you :)

Comment: why not adding code, it's not simplier ? than showing your structure like this ?

Comment: `removes the children elements from the flow, thus it's parent has no height.` add `overflow:hidden` to parent when using floating to avoid this

Comment: @TemaniAfif That actually worked perfectly! Thank you so much man

Comment: you can always post your code and we can provide with better alignement method than floating ;) (if you still want of course)

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. My objective was to center div.image vertically within the parent div. That usually would not be possible if both div.image and article elements were positioned absolutely. By floating both and leaving article positioned relatively, I was able to accomplish this and have the div.image element positioned absolutely, the parent element retaining it's height with your suggestion of overflow:hidden applied to it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **text-align** property for the parent and it can be used as text-align:left; or right or center. For this the parent should be display block and width specified and the inner element should be set to display:inline-block to avoid unnecessary errors

Comment: did you read the question ? :) he said `I have tried using margin-left: 0; margin-right; 0; text-alight: right or left`. And you answer is to broad like the question. So how can you be sure this will work in his case since you don't have any code

Comment: Yeah! I read the code and tried my best to give the answer since he havent posted code yet. So, is he is not going to get the answer if he is not sharing the code? We should give him the possibilities which works so if he is skipping any idea to align elements, then it should work! :-)